# Cache maintained by caller app or by provider app in microservices inter-app communication?

Tags: rest, microservices, caching, rpc

Suppose there are `app1` and `app2` in a microservices.
`app2` needs to call `app1`'s RESTful APIs.
Cache is needed since the call will be frequent. So after a successful RESTful call, there will be cache available for `app2`.

My question is who maintains the cache, `app1` or `app2`?
Any comparison between the two? Is there industry best practices?

In addition, are there any differences if there's a `app3` also needs to call the `app1`'s APIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is only one requester (one instance) that uses `app1`, then it doesn't really matter where the caching is done. As soon as a second requester comes into the picture (either a new app or a second instance), it will be most efficient to have the cache either in `app1` or in a separate caching server in front of `app1`, because

- only a single copy of the response needs to be cached, rather than a copy in each requester
- when two different requesters ask for the same data, the second one can be served the cached copy. That would not be possible if the cache was on the requester side.

As I mentioned above, the caching doesn't even have to be within the code of `app1`, but a dedicated caching server could be used. Then `app2` and `app3` would send their requests for `app1` to the caching server. If the server has a recent-enough response in their cache, then that response will be returned and otherwise the request is forwarded to `app1` and the response from `app1` is added to the cache. If the microservices use HTTP or HTTPS to communicate with each other, then you can use an off-the-shelf caching server.

If you use caching outside `app1`, then you have to determine for how long it is acceptable, in the worst case, that the cache serves old information while new information has just become available in `app1`. If the data at an endpoint can change without a write action occurring that is seen by the cache implementation, then you must put some time limit on how long the cache may regard the information as recent enough to serve it from the cache. In addition to this time limit, caching servers will also mark information as obsolete when they see a request to the same endpoint that has the semantics of (potentially) changing the data at that endpoint.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I also want to use a dedicated caching server like redis between `app1` and `app2`. But one thing I don't quite figure out is if `app2` maintains the cache, when `app1` updates some info, how will `app2` know the latest info?

Comment: @WeiHuang: I updated my answer

Comment: However, from one of my earlier search, [this discussion](https://dev.to/aldex32/comment/2d1l) seems not recommend shared cache.

Comment: @WeiHuang: In that discussion, the term "cache" is used with the meaning of "remember something locally to correlate asynchronous requests and responses with each other". That is a completely different kind of caching that can, by definition, only be done within the service that needs to do the correlation.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, a cache maintained and running close to the client/caller side scales much better for read-heavy service, while a cache maintained and running close to the server/callee side is easier to maintain for frequently updated data. In many scenarios, you may need both types of caches.

Broadly speaking, there are three types of cache invalidation strategy: expiry, token check (e.g. ETag), and push invalidation. Push invalidation is best for fast invalidation, but also the most resource intensive as both sides have to maintain an open connection at all time. Expiry is simple and scales very well, but quick invalidation is tricky.

In most cases, the server should be in control of caching, even when using a client-side cache. This can be done by the server advising the clients how and what can be cached and what invalidation mechanism to use explicitly on each request and response. In HTTP, this is usually done by using the Expires and Cache Control header (and a couple other headers to specify the exact caching semantic) or the ETag/If-Match/If-None-Match headers or by invitation to use web socket. HTTP provides a very rich vocabularies for the server to describe the caching requirements of a resource to the clients and any intermediary servers. As the other answer mentioned, if you use HTTP, you'll benefit from the widespread support of off the shelf caching components.

Another option is for the server to document how long the client are allowed to cache and how they invalidate and all clients just have to assume that, this may be ok if you control all endpoints and can co-ordinate a cache invalidation. But in very large networks with a diverse types of clients and intermediaries, this may be tricky to do correctly, so you may want to consider negotiating caching explicitly anyway. The benefit of implicit caching is that your communication protocol is cleaner, as it doesn't need to waste bytes negotiating caches; if your microservice network exchanges large number of small packets, where these negotiation overhead are problematic, implicitly negotiated caching may be the only sensible way to go.

Comment: Thank you Lie! I really learnt a lot from your reply especially the cache invalidation part.